# Rails url_for with a controller causing infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller, called 'textbook_url' that I generated with `rails g controller`, has only one route that I added manually:

`get 'textbook_url/:id' => 'textbook_url#show', as: 'textbook_url'`

Now I want to be able to use `url_for controller: textbook_url, id: 111`and have it return `/textbook_url/111`. However I believe that I missed something because calling url_for on this controller causes an infinite loop, as pictured.
[image]

Do I need to customise the url_options method of my controller for url_for to work?

Comment: `textbook_url` is bad name name for a controller as rails has its predefined `path` and `url` helpers(`*_url`) which may be conflicting in your case. Try changing the name of the controller.

Comment: That sounds plausible but I don't think anything changed after I changed the controller name. http://i.imgur.com/XS4CM4K.png

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the "return super unless" line?  That's the one that's causing the infinite loop.

Comment: That's part of rails